# Big O notation for a matrix algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, big-o

I have a simple algorithm that prints the two dimensional matrix (m*n, m and n are different numbers):

```cs
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",A[i,j]);
```

I read that the big O notation for this algorithm is O(n^2);
Could somebody explain me what is the "n^2" in that statement? If this is number of elementary operations, then it should be m*n, not n^2?

Comment: There seems to be an implicit assumption here that m = O(n).

Comment: in statement O(n^2) what is n?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

Comment: @user3660090 in `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` what is n?

Comment: in for(j=0;j<n;j++) n is the number of elements in a row

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: O(n^2) -Multiplying two n-digit numbers by a simple algorithm; bubble sort (worst case or naive implementation), Shell sort, quicksort (worst case), selection sort or insertion sort. From Wikipedia

Comment: in O(n^2) n is a number of elements in a row or number of elements at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality it should me m*n. We can assume it to be the number of elementary operations in this case, but the actual definition is its "the upper bound of the number of elementary operations."

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, time complexity of for the specified block of code is `O(n * m)`.
In simple words, that means your algo does `<= k * n * m` operations, k is some small constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

With for-loops, the complexity is measured as O(N) * the block inside the for-loop. The first for-loop contains a second for-loop so the complexity would be 0(N) * 0(N) = O(N^2). The inner for-loop contains a simple output statement, which has a complexity of 0(1) The N corresponds to the number of inputs so the time taken to execute the code is proportional to the number of items squared.

Answer (score 0):

first for loop runs for m-1 times and second for loop runs for n-1 times..

m-1 times = 1+2+3....m-1 times (same for second forloop)

we know that sum of natural numbers is x(x-1)/2 = x^2/2 - x/2

there are 2 loops so adding them gives you 2(x^2/2-x/2)

in Bing O notation we consider only the most dominant value and ignore coefficients, so we get x^2

so O(N) = x^2